# <button> behavior in Firefox vs IE

Tags: html, forms

I have a table, and at the end of each row, there is a button so the user can delete that row. I'm doing it like this:

```
<td><button type=submit name=delete value=1>delete</button>
<td><button type=submit name=delete value=2>delete</button>
<td><button type=submit name=delete value=3>delete</button>
<td><button type=submit name=delete value=4>delete</button>
```

But this doesn't work in IE, the form sends delete instead of value.
I've also tried:

```
<td><input type=submit name=delete value=1>
<td><input type=submit name=delete value=2>
<td><input type=submit name=delete value=3>
<td><input type=submit name=delete value=4>
```

But then the button text is a number instead of the word delete.

Is there anyway I can add a bunch of submit buttons to a form that all say delete but perform different actions? I can't use separate forms since forms can't nest.

Comment: But you can use different `fieldsets` within your form, and each fieldset can -I think- have its own submit/reset/whatever buttons.

Comment: This is a known bug in Internet Explorer, finally fixed in version 8.

Comment: You need to have each Button with it's own form. If your design won't let you do that then your design is probably flawed - use CSS rather than tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some JavaScript and a hidden form field?

```
<input type="hidden" name="deleteID" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteID(theid)
{
    theFormName.deleteID = theid;
    theFormName.submit();
}
</script>
```

And for the buttons:

```
<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:deleteID(1);" /></td>
<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:deleteID(2);" /></td>
<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:deleteID(3);" /></td>
<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:deleteID(4);" /></td>
```

And in the server side script, you can check if `deleteID` is set and delete as necessary.

Comment: I finally got this to work. It won't work if you name your submit button "submit". Whoops.

Answer (score 2):

Unrelated to your question: *always* put double quotes around your attribute values.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 6 and 7 both have buggy form handling support, especially with `button` elements:

1. The `innerText` of a `button` element is submitted, instead of the `value` (if set).
2. All `button` elements are successful, so all name/value pairs are submitted. This means if #1 would have worked correctly, it would delete all items :(
3. If the `type` attribute is not set on the `button`, it won't default to `submit`. So you have to add `type="submit"` to every `button`.

Possible ways to overcome this problem could be:

1) Create multiple `form`s with a hidden field containing the `value`:

```
<form action=".../delete" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
<form action=".../delete" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

2) Add the `id` inside the `button`, so you can parse it on the server side:

```
<button type="submit" value="1">Delete <span>1</span></button>
```

CSS:

```
button span {
    display: none;
}
```

C#:

```
int id;
if (!Int32.TryParse(this.Request.Form["delete"], out id)
{
    // Get the value between the `span`s
}
```

3) Use JavaScript to submit the `value` instead of the `innerText` and only successful `button`s:

[IE8.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

There is no 'best' answer, it just depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I wouldn't go with multiple submit buttons. It'd be better to set a hidden input to the value you want (using Javascript) when the buttons are clicked. Then the javascript can call myform.submit()

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a link?

You can also change the name for each button, but the link is better, I believe, as you are not really submitting a form, but doing an action.

Comment: I was using a link originally, but a link can only do a GET not a POST. And GET should be used when the form processing is idempotent.

Comment: Very bad idea: what happens when Google follows the links? Everything gets deleted. Also, some browser accelerators will prefetch links, so even behind a firewall on an intranet, there's a risk something will delete all your data automatically.

Comment: True, I forgot about Google, but in this situation just create a separate form for each button, with a hidden field for that row, and then use the POST action.

Answer (score 0):

Use links if you can

```
 <td><a href='delete.php?id=1'>delete</a></td>
```

If you insist on using forms use this one

```
 <td>
   <form action='delete.php'>
      <input type='hidden' name='id' value='2'>
      <input type='button' value='delete'>
   </form>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I try to avoid any javascript for that kind of problem.

Thanks to the Label tag that triggers any form element with an ID attribute.

```
<label for="action_delete" class="button-submit"><input type="submit" id="action_delete" name="action" value="delete" /> Delete this item</label>
```

Then use CSS to style the label as a button

```
label.button-submit{ cursor: pointer; ... }
label.button-submit input{ position: absolute; top: -999%; }
```

Cheers!